# How to retrieve the first X objects with unique attribute value

Tags: python, django

In one of my Django application, I am looking for an elegant and performant solution for a problem that could be described with the following example :

Given these objects:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Book(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection)
    publication = models.DateField()

class Collection(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

I would like to retrieve the 4 (or any other small number) latest published books but I want to have also 4 different authors. Meaning that if the 2 latest published books are from the same author, I only want to get one in my top 4 et leave 3 spots for other authors.

I have thought of doing this in multiple steps, retrieving latest publication, then testing one by one and storing the author value and if it was present multiple time i would retrieve more latest publication... but this being done on my home page, i need this code to be as efficient as possible.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: write a stored procedure for that and retrieve the dataset from it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `annotate`, `extra` or `raw`. Here's how you'd use `annotatate`:

```
books = [a.book_set.latest('pub_date') for a in Author.objects
                   .annotate(latest=Max('book__pub_date'))
                   .order_by('-latest')[:5]]
```

Assuming the authors don't have multiple books with the same `pub_date` you could use `extra` like this:

```
sql = '''SELECT MAX(app_book.pub_date)
         FROM app_book
         WHERE app_book.author_id=app_author.id'''
latest = Author.objects.extra(
                select={'latest': sql},
                order_by=['-latest'])[:5].values_list('latest')
books = Book.objects.filter(pub_date__in=[x[0] for x in latest]).order_by('-pub_date')
```

If you use `raw` you could grab all the books with a single query:

```
sql = '''SELECT * FROM app_book
         WHERE app_book.pub_date IN
           (SELECT MAX(app_book.pub_date)
            FROM app_book
            GROUP BY app_book.author_id)
         ORDER BY app_book.pub_date DESC'''
books = list(Book.objects.raw(sql)[:5])
```

I'm assuming models like the following:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = 'pub_date'
```

For fun I thought I'd benchmark the three approaches (using a db filled with about 100k dummy books):

```
>>> %time annotate()
(0.274) SELECT "app_author"."id", "app_author"."name", MAX("app_book"."pub_date") AS "latest" FROM "app_author" LEFT OUTER JOIN "app_book" ON ("app_author"."id" = "app_book"."author_id") GROUP BY "app_author"."id", "app_author"."name", "app_author"."id", "app_author"."name" ORDER BY "latest" DESC LIMIT 5; args=()
(0.035) SELECT "app_book"."id", "app_book"."title", "app_book"."author_id", "app_book"."pub_date" FROM "app_book" WHERE "app_book"."author_id" = 10  ORDER BY "app_book"."pub_date" DESC LIMIT 1; args=(10,)
(0.036) SELECT "app_book"."id", "app_book"."title", "app_book"."author_id", "app_book"."pub_date" FROM "app_book" WHERE "app_book"."author_id" = 9  ORDER BY "app_book"."pub_date" DESC LIMIT 1; args=(9,)
(0.036) SELECT "app_book"."id", "app_book"."title", "app_book"."author_id", "app_book"."pub_date" FROM "app_book" WHERE "app_book"."author_id" = 8  ORDER BY "app_book"."pub_date" DESC LIMIT 1; args=(8,)
(0.036) SELECT "app_book"."id", "app_book"."title", "app_book"."author_id", "app_book"."pub_date" FROM "app_book" WHERE "app_book"."author_id" = 7  ORDER BY "app_book"."pub_date" DESC LIMIT 1; args=(7,)
(0.040) SELECT "app_book"."id", "app_book"."title", "app_book"."author_id", "app_book"."pub_date" FROM "app_book" WHERE "app_book"."author_id" = 6  ORDER BY "app_book"."pub_date" DESC LIMIT 1; args=(6,)
CPU times: user 0.32 s, sys: 0.15 s, total: 0.47 s
Wall time: 0.47 s
<<< [<Book: Susan>, <Book: Yasmin>, <Book: Carl>, <Book: Benny>, <Book: George>]

>>> %time extra()
(0.445) SELECT (SELECT MAX(app_book.pub_date)
             FROM app_book
             WHERE app_book.author_id=app_author.id) AS "latest" FROM "app_author" ORDER BY "latest" DESC LIMIT 5; args=()
(0.045) SELECT "app_book"."id", "app_book"."title", "app_book"."author_id", "app_book"."pub_date" FROM "app_book" WHERE "app_book"."pub_date" IN (2038-11-25 11:33:30.425836, 2038-11-24 11:33:30.424598, 2038-11-23 11:33:30.423435, 2038-11-22 11:33:30.422227, 2038-11-21 11:33:30.421045) ORDER BY "app_book"."pub_date" DESC; args=(u'2038-11-25 11:33:30.425836', u'2038-11-24 11:33:30.424598', u'2038-11-23 11:33:30.423435', u'2038-11-22 11:33:30.422227', u'2038-11-21 11:33:30.421045')
CPU times: user 0.32 s, sys: 0.18 s, total: 0.50 s
Wall time: 0.50 s
<<< [<Book: Susan>, <Book: Yasmin>, <Book: Carl>, <Book: Benny>, <Book: George>]

>>> %time raw()
(0.279) SELECT * FROM app_book
             WHERE app_book.pub_date IN
               (SELECT MAX(app_book.pub_date)
                FROM app_book
                GROUP BY app_book.author_id)
            ORDER BY app_book.pub_date DESC; args=()
CPU times: user 0.19 s, sys: 0.09 s, total: 0.28 s
Wall time: 0.28 s
<<< [<Book: Susan>, <Book: Yasmin>, <Book: Carl>, <Book: Benny>, <Book: George>]
```

Comment: Total number of SQL queries in your code is 6, isn't it? The desired result can be achieved with just 2 queries.

Comment: @dragoon How would you do it? The other way that came to mind was to use `raw` which would result in a single query.

Comment: See the link in my question, I agree with this solution, though somebody claimed that the solution does not work :/

Comment: @dragoon As far as I know, `distinct()` doesn't work that way. That approach shouldn't work.

Comment: Thank you for these great inputs. Author can actually have more than one book on the same date, so i can't use the extra option. Also I would like to avoid if possible any raw SQL query. I'm striving to understand your first options. But given the update in my question to clarify my data model, i don't see how to make it work with your proposal.

Comment: Well an easy way would be to just add an FK back to the author from the book model.

Comment: Thanks for this great testing. I found my way around using the annotate first proposed solution. Hope this help some other fellows.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this post answers your question

[Django: Distinct foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935921/django-distinct-foreign-keys)

Comment: Thanks the disctinct() approach is quite adapted, however as mentionned in the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.QuerySet.distinct it should not be used with an order_by query and I'm pretty positive I need one...