# Join with subquery in Django ORM

Tags: sql, django, django-orm

I want to run a filter using Django's ORM such that I get a distinct set of users with each user's most recent session. I have the tables set up so that a `user` has many `sessions`; there is a `User` and `Session` model with the `Session` model having a `user = models.ForeignKey(User)`.

What I've tried so far is `Users.objects.distinct('username').order_by('session__last_accessed')`, but I know that this won't work because Django puts the `session.last_accessed` column into the selection, and so it's returning me, for example, 5 duplicate usernames with 5 distinct sessions rather than the single recent session and user.

Is it possible to query this via Django's ORM?

Edit: Okay, after some testing with SQL I've found that the SQL I want to use is:

```
select user.username, sub_query.last_accessed from (
  select user_id, max(last_accessed) as last_accessed
  from session
  group by user_id
) sub_query
join user on
user.id = sub_query.user_id
order by sub_query.last_accessed desc
limit 5
```

And I can do `sub_query` via `Session.objects.values('user').annotate(last_accessed=Max('last_accessed'))`. How can I use this `sub_query` to get the data I want with the ORM?

Edit 2: Specifically, I want to do this by performing one query only, like the SQL above does. Of course, I can query twice and do some processing in Python, but I'd prefer to hit the database once while using the ORM.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4936064/2696165

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using mysql backend, the following solution can be useful:

```
users_in_session = Session.objects.values_list('user_id', flat=True)
sessions_by_the_user_list = Session.objects \
                            .filter(user__in=set(users_in_session)) \
                            .order_by('last_accessed').distinct()
```

If you use the `sub_query`, then `order_by('last_accessed')` function should be good enough to get data in ordered list. Although as far as I have tested these results seemed unstable.

#### Update:

You can try:

```
Session.objects.values('user') \
  .annotate(last_accessed=Max('last_accessed')) \
  .orde‌​r_by('last_accessed').distinct()
```

Comment: Although I can do it in Python by performing multiple queries, I'd like to do just one query like my SQL in edit of the OP, and since you're calling `list()` on `users_in_session`, that would call the database. Is it possible to perform with just one query?

Comment: No I mean, wouldn't your code call the database once in line 1 and again in line 3?

Comment: I am not sure, here `users_in_session` is a `ValuesQuerySet`.(which I am not sure that if its a lazy loading or not. If its lazy loading, then its a single query). I have removed list from answer(which was definitely creating multiple query)

Comment: @JoshuaSmock you can try like this: Session.objects.values('user').annotate(last_accessed=Max('last_accessed')).order_by('last_accessed').distinct()

Comment: I tried that query and it seems to work! If you update your answer with it, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Calling distinct('username') shouldn't return duplicate usernames ever. Are you sure you are using Django version that supports .dictinct(fields), that is Django version later than 1.4? Prior to Django 1.4 .distinct(fields) was accepted by the oRM, but it didn't actually do the correct DISTINCT ON query.

Another hint that things aren't working as expected is that .distinct(username).order_by(session__last_accessed) isn't a valid query - the order_by should have username as first argument because order_by must be prefixed with the field names in .distinct() call. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct for details.

Comment: That won't work necessarily because the distinct is being called on both `username` and `session.last_accessed`, and because `session.last_accessed` is distinct, it will return them all.

Comment: Users.objects.distinct('username').order_by('session__last_accessed') will not work at all in Django 1.4+. In versions prior to 1.4 that query is interpreted as Users.objects.distinct(True).order_by('session__last_accessed'). The .distinct(*fields) doesn't call distinct for both username and session.last_accessed.